# PubSub Google cloud

Tags: apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub

Hi I am getting this error when trying to run the Google Dataflow template example Pub/Sub to BigQuery using Eclipse.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:
AutoValue_JavascriptTextTransformer_FailsafeJavascriptUdf cannot be resolved to a type

at com.google.cloud.teleport.templates.common.JavascriptTextTransformer$FailsafeJavascriptUdf.newBuilder(JavascriptTextTransformer.java:275)
at com.google.cloud.teleport.templates.PubSubToBigQuery$PubsubMessageToTableRow.expand(PubSubToBigQuery.java:309)
at com.google.cloud.teleport.templates.PubSubToBigQuery$PubsubMessageToTableRow.expand(PubSubToBigQuery.java:1)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.applyInternal(Pipeline.java:537)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.applyTransform(Pipeline.java:491)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PCollection.apply(PCollection.java:299)
at com.google.cloud.teleport.templates.PubSubToBigQuery.run(PubSubToBigQuery.java:209)
at com.google.cloud.teleport.templates.PubSubToBigQuery.main(PubSubToBigQuery.java:165)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not an issue with Pub/Sub, BigQuery or Dataflow but rather with Eclipse. It indicates that the [Java Build Path](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/eclipse/eclipse_java_build_path.htm) is missing the `FailsafeJavascriptUdf` class. Usually the solution is essentially to ["turn it off and on again"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24683420/9251751).

Comment: the error is in all auto value lines eg..AutoValue cannot be resolved to a type I added the auto value jar also but it won't resolve